# What do you think of 1/session items? Or help me find a better way to solve this plot hook. I'm stumped

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, metagaming, plot-hooks

I wanted to give my players a homebrew item, but I'm having a hard time balancing it around in-game / in-universe limitations. Normally this is like 1/day, 1/encounter etc.

I was thinking of doing 1/session (once per d&d session). Is that too meta?

For specifics, this item is a tome of knowledge which will allow them to ask some # of questions (I'm thinking 2) per [some time frame]. The books knows everything its previous owners knew. I'm doing this so my players have an in game mechanic to help them find the items they need to take down the BBEG.

Alternatively, if you have a suggestion how my players can find the 'x old artifacts' that legend says are needed to kill the BBEG that would work too. I'm trying to have them find something to help them find the artifacts without an in game person just telling them where they all are or just having them wander into the items randomly (both of which don't seem satisfying).

Comment: As written, this is a bit too opinion based. Is there a particular reason you don't want your players to follow the avenues of seeking out individuals in-game who would know their answer? Why you wouldn't make the item simply a 1/day item? A reason you think that having a usage duration align with a per session frequency is superior to other standard durations?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Our site is set up for handling focused, specific queries, so it might take a little "hammering" to make this workable. We'll do our best with that here in the comments and please be patient if we refuse to directly answer etc, it's a site thing. On that note: Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: @Pyrotechnical Thanks for responding! Yes this is quite opinion base. Mostly just looking for help/suggestions (if this isn't the place for that where would be? If it is...).

My players are going to be looking for 7-10 mythical items (they don't know how many there are or what they are - information about the items has been lost to time/legend). All they know is that they exist and they want to find them. I'm trying to figure out a plot device to help them find these items.

Comment: If you just want sprawling broadranging feedback we maintain a list of [forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/52137) which are better suited than us.

Comment: Related questions: [How can I communicate setting and campaign information to the PCs without providing direct exposition myself or through a DMPC?](/questions/7012), [How can I deliver in-universe written lore to players without it being dry exposition?](/questions/142163)